# Squid2 on Debian 6 - No connection to the proxy

Tags: debian, proxy, squid

I'm trying to set up a proxy for web browsing only via my dev server. The very basic configuration worked and I was able to browse, now when I've tried to complicate the things, It suddenly stopped working and I get connection timeout in browser and my log files are empty.

What I've tried to achieve is restrict the proxy to my IP range in my country and set a basic http auth for it.

Here's my config

> acl all src all
>
> acl manager proto cache_object
>
> http_port 1302
>
> emulate_httpd_log on
>
> acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32
>
> acl Safe_ports port 1302
>
> auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid/ncsa_auth /etc/squid/squid_passwd
>
> auth_param basic children 5
>
> auth_param basic realm NiceIdea
>
> auth_param basic credentialsttl 2 hours
>
> auth_param basic casesensitive on
>
> acl israel src 84.108.0.0/16
>
> acl deb0rian proxy_auth REQUIRED
>
> http_access allow localhost
>
> http_access allow israel deb0rian
>
> http_access deny !Safe_ports
>
> http_access deny all
>
> visible_hostname nadinspes
>
> forwarded_for off
>
> header_access Via deny all
>
> header_access Forwarded-For deny all
>
> header_access X-Forwarded-For deny all
>
> access_log /var/logs/squid/access.log squid
>
> cache_log /var/logs/squid/cache.log
>
> cache_store_log /var/logs/squid/store.log

Any ideas why it stopped working?

Thanks! T_T

Answer (score 1):

Debian's localhost address is 127.0.1.1. A 32 netmask of 127.0.0.1 will not be included in the ACL.